# ATLAS-LAPACK not linking to BLAS

Tags: c, lapack, blas, atlas

I went to a standard ATLAS compile. All the tests pass, but when I am trying to compile with the following command:

```
gcc prog.c -o prog -I/home/atlas_build/include -L/home/atlas_build/lib -llapack -lcblas -lm
```

It gives a spew of errors:

```
dsyevr.f:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `lsame_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `lsame_'
/home/atlas_build/lib/liblapack.a(dsyevr.o):dsyevr.f:(.text+0x1ac): more undefined references to `lsame_' follow
/home/atlas_build/lib/liblapack.a(dsyevr.o): In function `dsyevr_':
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x39e): undefined reference to `xerbla_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x742): undefined reference to `dscal_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x7cb): undefined reference to `dscal_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x9cb): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0xa15): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0xa84): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0xac2): undefined reference to `dcopy_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x1146): undefined reference to `dscal_'
dsyevr.f:(.text+0x124b): undefined reference to `dswap_'
```

It goes on and on, complaining about BLAS functions missing like dscal_, dcopy_, etc. I have truncated the output. Why is this happening?

Comment: That error is not from compiler, but the linker. There is apparently a libray missing or on a different path. (disclaimer: I do not know about Atlas, so I cannot be more specific).

Comment: I suspect that you have built your executable and you have moved it somewhere other than where it was when you compiled it (or maybe not) and now it cannot find the library. You either need to set an `rpath` during link or need to set and export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to the directory containing it. [**Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries**](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) is a decent tutorial. See [**Linking LAPACK/BLAS libraries**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801297/linking-lapack-blas-libraries?rq=1) first.

Comment: I did export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The link you sent does not help. All of the functions won't link, not just some.

Comment: you have to link against fortran blas `-lblas`

Comment: ^Hi, how do I do that? I don't seem to have -lblas. I tried to link against `-lf77blas` and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this. Need to link against lgfortran.